# problem with extract region pixels from gray image on Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I would to like to selection the dark gray pixels from gray image.
[image]

```
J = rgb2gray(I);
Newfigure = zeros(size(J));
[k,l] =find(J<130);  
Newfigure(k,l) = J(k,l);
imshow(Newfigure)
```

when visualize the `Newfigure`, I see the zone of circle like square. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the way you index into `Newfigure`. Look at the following:

```
>> test = zeros(10);
>> test([2,8], [1,2]) = 1

test =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

This is different from

```
>> test = zeros(10);
>> test(2, 1) = 1;
>> test(8, 2) = 1

test =

     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

You could either use a loop like

```
Newfigure = zeros(size(J)); 
for n = 1:numel(k); 
    Newfigure(k(n), l(n)) = J(k(n), l(n)); 
end
```

or simply use

```
Newfigure = J < 130;
imshow(Newfigure);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the `find(...)` and just use logical indices. It'll be faster too...

```
J = rgb2gray(I);
Newfigure = zeros(size(J));
tf = J<130;  
Newfigure(tf) = J(tf);
imshow(Newfigure)
```

The `tf` variable will be an array of 0s/1s (true/false), the same size as `J` which you can then use to index the arrays as shown.